# Submit Rails form via AJAX request without jQuery and remote: true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, rails-ujs

I am creating a blog to my website where users can add comments to a post. I want the form for a new comment to submit a "POST" request via AJAX and use javascript to load the new comment instead of the old nasty page refresh.

I am quite new to AJAX, so its a bit confusing. It's basically just simple scaffolding-like CRUD stuff. Here is some of my code so far:

The form in the view:

```
    <%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, class: 'form-line' %>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter, class: 'form-line' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :comment, class: 'form-line' %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-line' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit 'Comment', id: 'comment-btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My comments belong to the post which has many comments. Here is my comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.save!
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body, :post)
  end

end
```

I am getting an HTTP 500 error code in the chrome dev tools network section. In the general tab it says:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/en/posts/1/comments
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Any idea where I am going wrong and what I am missing in my controller here?

Thanks

Comment: What does your console output look like?

Comment: Can you also post the server side error  please?

Comment: By default, rails form is set for html request. To set `request.xhr = 0`, you have to provide `remote: true`

Comment: Thanks guys! I removed this and now it's working, even without remote: true. 

respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json
      end